# Replacing 0/-1 boolean in DLookup with Active/Inactive

Tags: ms-access, combobox, vba, ms-access-2010

I tried to do an If statement in the control source with my DLookup, but that didn't work.

This is for EmployeeStatus within the Employee table - I'm displaying the EmployeeStatus in a subform. However, using my DLookup, it only displays the status as a 0 or -1.

```
=DLookUp("ActiveEmployee","Employee","EmployeeID=" & [cboEmployee])
```

How can I get 0/-1 to be Active/Inactive instead?

Comment: be aware that `Dlookup` can be super slow if you're `Employee` table is big. I'd bet you could include `ActiveEmployee` as a field in your form's recordset then you can save a whole query.

Comment: Nevermind, I got it resolved.

Comment: Basically, I wrapped the DLookup in an IIF and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
IIF(DLookUp("ActiveEmployee","Employee","EmployeeID=" & [cboEmployee]) = 0, "Active", "Inactive")
```

I'm not 100% sure of how your data is being stored, however you said the `DLookup` is returning either 0 or -1 (False or True) to evaluate what is being returned by the `DLookup`. As a side note - it is well-known that `Lookup` functions perform very slowly as tables become of medium-large size. If speed is a factor, I would probably take a different approach.

That being said, we can use `IIF()` which is essentially:

```
IIF(If this statement = something, 
What do you want to return if it's True,  
What do you want to return if it's False)
```

Easy example:

`IIF(Left("OverMind", 1) = "O", "O is the first letter in OverMind", "O is not the first letter in OverMind")`

In my answer :

If the `DLookup` returns a 0, return "Active". If the `DLookup` returns a -1 (or anything else), return "Inactive".

Comment: @Takendarkk Feel free to edit it if you see room for improvement. I tried to throw a quick example as well as explain in plain english to help OP understand,